# Issue when migrating Android build files to declarative form

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Due to the changes in Flutter 3.19 regarding the [Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply), I had to migrate my files in order to work with the new version. However, after following the guide, I keep running into this issue:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Android Studio Projects\Traux\TeamNews-App\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AppPlugin$ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
         > Cannot have abstract method AndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType().
```

This is my `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.1.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

My `android/build.grade`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my `app/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.ingressosa.santa_cruz_news"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

What can I do here? I've tried deleting my **pubspec.lock** file and running:

`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`
`flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: If I were you, I'd try upgrading Android Gradle Plugin and Gradle versions.